# Why Is My Variable Not Working As A Parameter In PHP Funtion

Tags: php, mysql, function, loops, parameters

At the very top of my document I created a varible called $selectedID using $_GET to get the id of the selected user(ill later switch it to an encrypted string) so the url looks a little like this profile.php?id=4. I then have a function which loops though a database for all the blog post with the same number as the $selectedID variable, which is inputted as the second parameter of the function.

**The issue is that the second parameter in my function $selectedId Is supposed to be used as a number to filter by while looping through my database, but it seems like the variable is not properly being inserted into my function therefore the loop is not working properly**

This is my main page showing the information

```
<div id="blogFeed">
                            <ul>
                            <!-- Exicute the fucntion from the functions.inc.php which grabs all the feed articles from the database -->
                            <?php

                                $_result = display_blogs_profile($connect, $selectedId);
                                // Count how many rows are in the database
                                $limit = count($_result);

                                // Loop through all the articles(rows) from the database
                                for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++){
                                    // Define varibles for each column
                                    $id         = $_result[$i][6];
                                    $title      = $_result[$i][0];
                                    $date       = $_result[$i][1];
                                    $article    = $_result[$i][2];
                                    $photo      = $_result[$i][3];
                                    $icon       = $_result[$i][4];
                                    $author     = $_result[$i][5];
                                    $findAuthor = $_result[$i][7];
                                    $feedRadius = "50px";
                                    $iconPhoto   = "newsRed.png";
                                    $photo       = $_result[$i][3];
                                    $feedRadius  = "0px";
                                    $contentLink = "Read More";
                                    $realignIcon = 'margin-right: -195px;';


                                // Only show the first 10 articles the stop building the html
                                if((string)$employeeID != $findAuthor){
                                    continue;
                                }else{
                            ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="eventBoxImage" style="background: url('images/<?php echo $photo ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: center; border-radius: 50px"></div>
                                    <div class="eventContentContainer">
                                        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                                        <h4>Posted By: <?php echo $author; ?></h4>
                                        <h5><?php echo $date ?></h5>
                                        <p><?php echo $article ?></p>
                                        <h6><a href="blog.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $contentLink ?></a></h6>
                                        <span style="background: url('images/<?php echo $iconPhoto ?>') no-repeat; <?php echo $realignIcon; ?> background-size: 45px;"><a href="#"></a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php }}?> <!-- Close php loop -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="blogPostContainer">
                            <h1 class="blog">Create Blog Post</h1>
                            <form class="blog" action="includes/insert.php" method="post">
                                <input name="blogTitle" type="text" placeholder="Enter The Blog Title" required/>
                                <input  name="blogArticle" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter Your Blog Post" required/>
                                <input name="blogSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div id="profileSearch">
                            <div id="searchBar">
                                <form id="search" action="index.php" method="POST">
                                    <div id="searchIcon"></div>
                                    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Through <?php echo $firstName ?>'s Posts" onkeyup="searchQ();" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="editId" id="editId" value="<?php echo $employeeID ?>" />
                                    <div id="userResults">

                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And here is the function

```
function display_blogs_profile($connect, $selectId)
            {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM intranet";
                $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                $finalArray = array();
                $i = 0;

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $id =  $selectId;
                    $title =  $row['title'];
                    $date =  $row['date'];
                    $article =  $row['article'];
                    $photo =  $row['photo'];
                    $icon =  $row['icon'];
                    $authorID =  $row['findAuthor'];
                    $author =  $row['author'];
                    if($row['icon'] === "3" && $authorID === $selectId){
                        $finalArray[$i] =  array($title, $date, $article, $photo, $icon, $author, $id, $authorID);
                    }
                    $i++;
                }   
                    $finalArrayDesc = array_reverse($finalArray);
                    return $finalArrayDesc;
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: not working **HOW**?

Comment: Have you verified that `$selectID` is being passed into the function with even an `echo`?

Comment: If `$selectedID = $_GET['id']` then your `if{}` will be true, so it will never reach the `display_blogs_profile($connect, $selectedId)` in your `else{}`. And the reverse - if your `else{}` is invoked, then `$selectedID` would be `null`, which would cause your `display_blogs_profile($connect, $selectedId)` to fail as that means `$_GET['id']` is not set.

Comment: @Rizier123: that'd get expensive to debug...

Comment: @Sean If `id` isn't set, then the `if` statement evaluates to be false, you're making an assumption that it always is set. Though I do agree that is probably the most likely cause of the issue.

Comment: where are you setting this $selectedId first of all I don't see $selectedID = $_GET['id'] anywhere

Comment: Well, from your shared code I don't see you declaring $selectedId to $_GET['id'] anywhere, but maybe it is declared somewhere along with $connect.

Answer (score 0):

This is true

> "it seems like the variable is not properly being inserted"

That is because it was never set.  Try this:

```
$selectedID = $_GET['id'];
```

right after the check of `if(isset($_GET['id']))` so

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $selectedID = $_GET['id'];
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks for all the help! The if Get statement and the if $employeeID != $findAuthor statement would break or continue the loop no matter what unless on my own account. I just had to take the $employeeID != $findAuthor statement out :)